# Iterate over an optional list of integers ifPresent

Tags: list, lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have an Optional list of integers. I wish to see if the list is actually present and then convert it into a stream. One way of doing this is

```
Optional<List<Integer>> listOfNumbers = ...
if (listOfNumbers.isPresent()) {
    listOfNumbers.get().stream();
}
```

But, I dont wish to have that if condition. I searched and saw that `ifPresent()` does the same thing but when I do `listOfNumbers.ifPresent(this::get))`, I get the following error:

> non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Can you please help me do this in an efficient manner? This is still new to me so if there's anything incorrect in my understanding please let me know.

Comment: `listOfNumbers.orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()...` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, the cleanest way to get a `Stream` is to use `Optional.orElse` method with `Collections.emptyList`:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = listOfNumbers.orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream();
```

The other possible solution with `Optional.map`:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = listOfNumbers.map(List::stream).orElse(Stream.empty());
```

Comment: I like the second version best. I think it’s more to the point because we really have no need for an empty list, just an empty stream,

Answer (score 4):

**Update Java 9 :**

Since jdk9, `Optional` has a new method `stream()`, which returns either a stream of one element, or an empty stream.

Thus, going from an `Optional<List<Integer>>` to an `Stream<Integer>` becomes

```
Stream<Integer> streamOfNumbers = listOfNumbers.stream().flatMap(List::stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is How I did that on my last Project.

```
Optional<List<Integer>> listOfNumbers = ...

listOfNumbers.ifPresent((numbers) -> {
...
});
```

The `ifPresent` will check if the size of your Optional variable reaches it's limit and loop through your list.

You can replace `ifPresent` with `forEach` if you want to do it separately instead.